# Eclipse Type Font Color

Tags: eclipse

I am moving to Eclipse from VS.
For me it is much more rich IDE but there is some VS feature I miss: set types (like: String, MyType etc.) color to be different from other text.

In Eclipse I found many themes that change the whole look, but I don't want to change the default theme completely. I only want to color types so it will be easy to notice them.

I guess the option is exist, I just can't find it.

Comment: Next time you are looking for a preference, you can try searching for them in the Search box in the Preferences Dialog. You can find them youself :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to configure that from here:

Menu: Window >> Preferences >> [language] >> Editor >> Syntax Coloring

Comment: For the sake of helping others, the sub-property is 'Classes' in the case of this question.